# Some MySQL queries from web does not work, some queries work very well, some queries just work with IE

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, opencart

Some Genius help!!!!!!
1) Interface
[image: user mySQL queries to generate CSV files]

2) click button ----> MySQL query will show in the box ----> click button "generate CSV" 
3) Query "Get product base" always work, "Price base" work on IE several times, then stopped working.

```
<li>
    <input type=button style="width:800px;height:30px;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"
    value="Price base"
    sql="select p.model, pd.name, p.ws_price, p.rt_price, p.pc
           from product p, product_description pd
          where p.product_id = pd.product_id
          order by substr(p.model,3,4)"
    />
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type=button style="width:800px;height:30px;text-align:left;padding-left:20px;"
    value="Get product base"
    sql="select p.model, p.sku, pd.name_for_sales, p.quantity, p.ws_price, p.rt_price
      from product p, product_description pd
     where p.product_id = pd.product_id
    " 
    />
  </li>
```

3)

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').bind('click',function(e){
        $tgt = $(e.target);
        $sql = $tgt.attr('sql');
        $('textarea')[0].value = $sql;
    });

   $('.excel').bind('click',function(e){
       //$sql = $('textarea').html().trim();
       var ta = $('textarea');
       $sql = $('textarea')[0].value;
       //alert($sql);
       $url = '<?php echo $lnk_export; ?>' + '&sql=' + $sql;
       //alert($url);
       location.href = $url;
      });

   });
    //-->
 </script>
```

Comment: You are letting users execute any SQL they want on your server? What errors do you receive, are you using error reporting?

Comment: Don't make up custom attributes. If you need to put user data in HTML elements, use `data-XXX`, e.g. `data-sql`.

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Comment: It is a internal use website.  the error is "The connection was reset".  How to use error reporting?

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: That often means that the PHP script timed out. This could happen if the query takes too long to process.

Comment: Check the server error log to see if there are any details there.

Comment: increased "mysql.connect_timeout"  to 200000, still same issue.  Sometimes the query runs for several times, then stopped.